# Why is my CSS file overridden with another stylesheet?

Tags: asp.net, css

I developed an application, and I used header and footer from another app. I created a separate style sheet for my app, called TestStyleapp.css. When I run my new application, the stylesheet I used from the other app is overriding my new CSS file.

Is there a way to include/reference the Teststyleapp.css (I tried calling it last) other than using `!important` in front of all the elements in teststyleapp.css?

When I use FireBug, I do not see Teststyleapp.CSS at all.

Comment: Learn about [specificity](http://css-tricks.com/855-specifics-on-css-specificity/). Also, we will need to see some code if you want a more specific answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="TestStyleapp.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

It should be linked as such, between the head tags. Make sure the case is correct. I like using all lowercase and _ as a word separator. Just my personal style.

First, get the .css file to show in the NET tab in Firebug and we'll take it from there.

Comment: I changed the classes that are same. So when I run it locally I am doing <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> which is working fine. When I deploy it to the server I am changing the link rel to  
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:/inetpub/wwwroot/NewApp/css/style.css" /> which is working good. When I click on Newapp and browse I am seeing the form with correct styles applied to it. Newapp.myorgname.com is coming up good. But If I use the same link on my machine it is not using the style.css what is wrong?

Comment: So my problem is when I run it locally on the local host it is working fine. When I deploy it to the server when I check the link on server it is working fine. But when I use the same link on my local machine the stylesheet is getting over rided or deleted ...etc Not working.

Comment: when I include http://testapp.myorgname.com/css/style.css as a referance on the server in the firebug I am seeing The resource from this URL is not text:  when I clicked on source edit.

Comment: First off, comment out all stylesheets but the one you want show. Try and get that to work. Is there a link to page that I can inspect? Seems it is probably just a linking issue.

Comment: It is working now. The issue is when I am calling testapp.myorgname.com/css/style.css it is coming as resource not found because of permissions. When I moved the css to accessible place it started working. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Even if it is LAST, if it is NOT more SPECIFIC (the other page items are more specific) it will not override what is above it in the stack.

Example:

```
div .myclass (background-color: red);
```

other (yours has)

```
.myclass(background-color:green);
```

you still see red.